# Logic condition to avoid duplicate entries in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure . I'm trying to insert the users from the table usuaris, whose admin variable is equal to 1, into the table that the stored procedure creates with the name( `nombre varchar(50)`) that is passed as a parameter.

When the procedure is called, it duplicates the user 'mary' with `id` 4. I've tried a couple of ways to implement the logic condition in order to avoid the duplication, but still, I'm missing something and I can't get the desired result. In the code below, the logic condition before the insertion is the last thing I've tried. Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createNewtable`(nombre varchar(50))
 BEGIN

 /*variable declaration*/

 declare centinela int ;
 declare id1 int ;
 declare nom1 varchar(50);
 declare admin1 enum('0','1') ;

 declare cadena varchar(100);    /*string to concatenate table creation and insertion*/


 /*cursor declaration*/

 declare cursor1 cursor for select * from users.usuaris where admin = '1' ;
 declare continue handler for not found set @centinela = 1 ;


  /*create the table with the name that's passed as parameter*/

  set @cadena=concat("create table ",nombre,                 
               "(
                 id2 int not null primary key,
                 nom2 varchar(50),
                 admin2 enum ('0','1')
                 )" );

   prepare stmt from @cadena ;
   execute stmt ;
   deallocate prepare stmt;


/* loop that fetches the data from the table usuaris and 
 inserts them into the newly created table. */

  set @centinela = 0 ;
  open cursor1 ;

  bucle: loop
     fetch cursor1 into id1,nom1,admin1 ;

   if ( centinela = 1 ) then
    leave bucle ;
       end if ;

       /*logic condition to avoid entry duplication */

       if not exists (select * from users.usuaris where admin='1' and id=@id1) then
         set @cadena=concat("insert into ",nombre," values( ",id1,",'",nom1,"','",admin1,"')");
       end if;

      select @cadena;
      prepare stmt from @cadena;
      execute stmt ;
      deallocate prepare stmt;

  end loop bucle;
  close cursor1;

END
```

Here is the  single-table database of users :

```
 create database if not exists `users` ;

 use  `users` ;

 create table usuaris(

  id int not null auto_increment primary key ,
  nom varchar(50),
  admin enum ('0','1')

  );


  insert into  usuaris(id,nom,admin)
  values 
       (1,'jose','1'),
       (2,'maria','0'),
       (3,'frank','1'),
       (4,'mary','1'),
       (5,'godfrey','0') ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also it has to duplicate `jose`. The reason of duplication -  if the `IF` statement isn't TRUE then you don't set the new `@cadena` variable BUT anyway execute PREVIOUS `@cadena` statement. You should move execution into the IF statement also:

```
   if not exists (select * from users.usuaris where admin='1' and id=@id1) then
     set @cadena=concat("insert into ",nombre," values( ",id1,",'",nom1,"','",admin1,"')");
     select @cadena;
     prepare stmt from @cadena;
     execute stmt ;
     deallocate prepare stmt;
    end if;
```

Also in SQL you should always try to avoid loops if it possible and use SQL statements instead.
You can replace your loop with one SQL statement:

```
INSERET INTO NEW_TABLE_NAME_HERE 
        SELECT id1,nom1,admin1 
        FROM users.usuaris where admin<>'1'
```

Further more you can use `SELECT INTO` statement syntax to automatically create new table without `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
    SELECT id1 as id2,
           nom1 as nom2,
           admin1 as admin2 
    INTO NEW_TABLE_NAME_HERE
    FROM users.usuaris where admin<>'1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ur below code to my new code and try-

Existing Code

```
if not exists (select * from users.usuaris where admin='1' and id=@id1) then
         set @cadena=concat("insert into ",nombre," values( ",id1,",'",nom1,"','",admin1,"')");
       end if;

      select @cadena;
      prepare stmt from @cadena;
      execute stmt ;
      deallocate prepare stmt;
```

New Code-

```
SET @cnt=SELECT count(*) FROM users.usuaris WHERE admin='1' AND id=@id1
    IF @cnt>0 THEN
         SET @cadena=CONCAT("insert into ",nombre," values( ",id1,",'",nom1,"','",admin1,"')");
      prepare stmt from @cadena;
      execute stmt ;
      deallocate prepare stmt;
       end if;
```